# How to track changes in one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column date where dates are sorted in ascending order and there are many repeating dates. In first column I have index that should be increased by 1 when the date changes.

now it looks like this

table a

```
index      date  
---------------------
1       2001-03-01  
1       2001-03-01  
1       2001-03-01  
1       2001-04-01  
1       2001-04-01  
1       2001-04-01  
1       2001-05-01
```

should look like this

table a

```
index   date  
-----------------
1      2001-03-01  
1      2001-03-01  
1      2001-03-01  
2      2001-04-01  
2      2001-04-01  
2      2001-04-01  
3      2001-05-01
```

thanks for help

Comment: Does not look like you are asking for help rather asking us to do on your behalf.

Comment: I am asking at least for a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired result, [dense_rank()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) analytic function can be used. Here is an example:

```
select dense_rank() over(order by date1) as index1
     , date1
  from tab_a
```

Result:

```
INDEX1      DATE1
--------------------
1         2001-03-01
1         2001-03-01
1         2001-03-01
2         2001-04-01
2         2001-04-01
2         2001-04-01
3         2001-05-01
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4b36/13)

As a side note. Try to avoid using reserved words such as `date` and `index` as column names.

Comment: Thanks! Just what i looked for. Haven't heard about this function before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CHANGETABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934145.aspx) for your case.

> Returns change tracking information for a table.You can use this
>   statement to return all changes for a table or change tracking
>   information for a specific row.

Comment: The problem is I am using t-sql and there are no triggers

Comment: Thank you for help. I used dense_rank function as Nicholas Krasnov said. Still read much about CHANGETABLE